# i cant enter recovery mode; how do i install my ADB driver?

Tags: adb, broken-screen, lg-g-stylo

Here is my issue. I have an LG g Stylo 3 Plus, (T-mobile). I can't get into recovery.

Here's the situation:

1. my **screen is broken** and I have a semi picture. However its unresponsive.
2. I had no need to root this phone before. So device is not **rooted**.
3. I enabled knock code. So I have important calls and texts that I am not receiving.

So I need to use ADB to unlock my phone and also side-load a mirror to pc apk.

I am familiar with ADB commands and have tried everything within my knowledge. I have also done extensive research and yes, I did also using the search bar.
Any ideas how to make this show up in adb without entering recovery mode?
so just to make this clear. I'm completely lost.

Comment: May I recommend you a look into our [broken-screen tag-wiki](/tags/broken-screen/info)? You're not the first in this situation, so some of our existing solutions might apply.

Answer (score 0):

If you display is at least partially usable, you may use a USB/micro-USB adapter to simply **plug a computer mouse** to your smartphone. From there and depending on your screen damage, you may more easily interact with your device.

Also, remember the screen rotation settings : if your ROM allows 360° rotation (i.e. 90°, 180°, and 270°), you should be able to see any part of the screen by turning it on the sides, and/or upside-down.